# Angular lazy one-time binding - dealing with expressions

Tags: angularjs

How do I apply one time lazy binding to the following where the value is composed of an expression:

```
<span ng-bind="::firstname + ' ' + ::lastname"></span> // breaks
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Why not composing them in your controller:

```
$scope.name = $scope.firstname + ' ' + $scope.lastname;
```

And then simply:

```
<span ng-bind="::name"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<span ng-bind="::(firstname + ' ' + lastname)"></span>
```

Parens aren't necessary though.